# Regex : Remove all commas between a quote separated string [python]

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

What would be an appropriate regex to remove all commas in a string as such:

```
12, 1425073747, "test", "1, 2, 3, ... "
```

Result:

```
12, 1425073747, "test", "1 2 3 ... "
```

What I have that matches correctly:

```
"((\d+), )+\d+"
```

However, I obviously cant replace this with $1 $2. I can't use "\d+, \d+" because it will match 12, 1425073747 which is not what I want. If someone can explain how to recursively parse out values that would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
>>> input = '12, 1425073747, "test", "1, 2, 3, ... "';
>>> print re.sub(r'(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$),', "", input);
12, 1425073747, "test", "1 2 3 ... "
```

`(?!(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` matches text only if inside quotea -- avoid matching even number of quotes after comma.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a `re.sub` with a simple `r'"[^"]*"'` regex and pass the match object to a callable used as the replacement argument where you may further manipulate the match:

```
import re
text = '12, 1425073747, "test", "1, 2, 3, ... "'
print( re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""), text) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/a6zOrH).

If the string between quotes may contain escaped quotes use

```
re.sub(r'(?s)"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""), text)
```

Here, `(?s)` is the inline version of a `re.S` / `re.DOTALL`  flag and the rest is the double quoted string literal matching pattern.

**Bonus**

- Removing all whitespace in between double quotes: `re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: ''.join(x.group().split()), text)`
- Remove all non-digit chars inside double quotes: `re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x.group() if c.isdigit()), text)`
- Remove all digit chars inside double quotes: `re.sub(r'"[^"]*"', lambda x: ''.join(c for c in x.group() if not c.isdigit()), text)`

Answer (score 0):

the solution offered by [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) was very useful, in fact the only one that worked from the guides that I found - that means really removed the semicolons reliably in quoted text. However, using it on a 640 kB text file (yes, 640) took like 3 minutes, which was not acceptable even on an oldish i5.

The solution for me was to implement a C++ function:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C" // required when using C++ compiler
    const char *
    erasesemi(char *s)
{
    bool WeAreIn = false;
    long sl = strlen(s);
    char *r = (char*) malloc(sl+1);
    strcpy(r, s);
    for (long i = 0; (i < (sl - 1)); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '"')
        {
            WeAreIn = not(WeAreIn);
        }
        if ((s[i] == ';') & WeAreIn)
        {
            r[i] = ',';
        }
        else
        {
            r[i] = s[i];
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

from what I found in the internets, I used this setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension

# Compile *mysum.cpp* into a shared library
setup(
    # ...
    ext_modules=[Extension('erasesemi', ['erasesemi.cpp'],), ],
)
```

after that you have to run

```
python3 setup.py build
```

the appropriate lines in the main code were:

```
import ctypes
import glob
libfile = glob.glob(
    'build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/erasesemi.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so')[0]

mylib = ctypes.CDLL(libfile)

mylib.erasesemi.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
mylib.erasesemi.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

..

data3 = mylib.erasesemi(str(data2).encode('latin-1'))
```

Like this, it produced the desired result in < 1 second. The most tricky part was to find out how to pass strings with german characters to the c++ function. Naturally, you can use any encoding you want.